# Java code giving javax/activation/MimeTypeParseException when using openjdk11

Tags: java, java-11

Below is the code

```
package TestPackage;
import com.ice.tar.TarArchive;
import com.ice.tar.TarEntry;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
public class mimeExceptionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    File archive=new File("/tmp/java-11.0.9-linux-x649971467672330028230.tmp/java-11.0.9-linux-x64.tar");

        System.out.println("---1--------");
        URL jarURL = new URL("file:" + "C:\\Users\\Test\\Downloads\\javax.activation-1.2.0.jar");
          URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{jarURL});
      
       // Load a class from the JAR using the new class loader
         
      try {
            classLoader.loadClass("javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException");
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
            Class.forName("javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException",true,classLoader);
            
            TarArchive tar = new TarArchive(new FileOutputStream(archive));
            
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      
      
        System.out.println("---2--------");
  
        // Start the new thread
         
         
    }
}
```

When we ran the above code we are getting output as below

```
---1--------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/MimeTypeParseException
    at TestPackage.mimeExceptionExample.main(mimeExceptionExample.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 1 more
```

My requirement is i don't want to add javax.activation-1.2.0.jar directly in the build path in eclipse. It needs to be loaded from the code. So can anyone please assist?

Comment: ... you want to load a dependency from the code at runtime? That's a very bad idea. You define your dependencies in your build script.

Comment: I have requirement where even after adding the jar from the script its not taking jar during packaging of a module. so i am trying with this approach.

Comment: `"file:" + "C:\\Users\\Test\\Downloads\\javax.activation-1.2.0.jar"` ← That is *not* a valid URL.  Backslash characters are not valid characters in a URL, on any platform.  Perhaps you wanted `Path.of("C:\\Users\\Test\\Downloads\\javax.activation-1.2.0.jar").toUri().toURL()`?

Comment: Tried the above code but still same error

Comment: Sometimes a sanity check is useful.  Split the code into multiple parts and verify that the .jar file exists:  `Path path = Path.of("C:\\Users\\Test\\Downloads\\javax.activation-1.2.0.jar"); System.out.println("JAF is readable: " + Files.isReadable(path)); URL jarURL = path.toUri().toURL();`

Comment: I have verified and the jar is taken but the issue is when it comes to the line  TarArchive tar = new TarArchive(new FileOutputStream(archive)); then the above error is coming.

Comment: can anyone please check and assist on the above issue?

Comment: What “above error”?  The only stack trace you’ve shown us is the one produced by calling ClassLoader.loadClass.

Comment: The Program i have shared  is a standalone program and i have a req where i need to load javax.activation-1.2.0.jar from java code so when the line "TarArchive tar = new TarArchive(new FileOutputStream(archive));"  is called, which requires MimeTypeParseException.class which is present in javax.activation-1.2.0.jar is available at runtime.

Comment: I’m not sure that setting the context classloader is sufficient to make `new TarArchive` see the class.  You probably will need to use your new ClassLoader to create the TarArchive.  It may be easier to do this by creating a separate class using that ClassLoader, which in turn performs all of the TarArchive calls.

Comment: @VGR i tried to replicate what you suggested but was not able to so can you provide the code snippet of the changes you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

As Jorn said, you are far better off setting the classpath at runtime.  If at all possible, you should do it that way.

But your question seems to indicate that you can’t, so…

The first problem is that URLs have a limited set of characters they are allowed to contain.  A URL is *not* allowed to contain a backslash character.

Therefore, this line is incorrect:

```
URL jarURL = new URL("file:" + "C:\\Users\\Test\\Downloads\\javax.activation-1.2.0.jar");
```

Why didn’t it throw an exception?  Because java.net.URL is a very old class.  It was part of Java 1.0.  It didn’t do rigorous checking of syntax.

Why didn’t they fix it?  Because in object-oriented design, you *never* break existing code that utilizes public classes and public class members.  So, instead, Java added a new class, [java.net.URI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html), which *does* do rigorous syntax checking.  This code would throw an exception, as it should:

```
URI uri = new URI("file:" + "C:\\Users\\Test\\Downloads\\javax.activation-1.2.0.jar");
```

The proper way to convert a file name to a URL is:

```
Path path = Path.of("C:\\Users\\Test\\Downloads\\javax.activation-1.2.0.jar");
assert Files.isReadable(path) : "File \"" + path + "\" does not exist!";

URL activationJarURL = path.toUri().toURL();
```

The second problem is that Java doesn’t use a thread’s context classloader.  So, calling `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);` essentially does nothing.  There do exist some libraries and some Java SE APIs that make use of the context classloader, but regular classloading won’t use it.

This actually does work:

```
Class.forName("javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException", true, classLoader);
```

But the next line is not using the new ClassLoader at all:

```
// Error --- not using classLoader, so cannot find javax.activation package
TarArchive tar = new TarArchive(new FileOutputStream(archive));
```

What you need is a separate class which can be loaded by `classLoader`, which in turn calls `new TarArchive`.  If that class is in the same .jar or module as your application, it almost certainly will already be loaded by the current ClassLoader and therefore will not see the activation classes, so it will need to be in a separate .jar (not just a separate package).

```
// This class must be in a separate .jar file.
public class ArchiveWriter
implements Runnable {
    private final File archive;

    public ArchiveWriter(File archive) {
        this.archive = Objects.requireNonNull(archive,
            "Archive file cannot be null.");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            TarArchive tar = new TarArchive(new FileOutputStream(archive));
            // etc.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now your `main` method can load that class using a custom ClassLoader which uses the [platform ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getPlatformClassLoader()) as a parent, and which refers to both the URL of the .jar containing the above class and the Java Activation Framework .jar.

```
Path jafJarPath =
    Path.of("C:\\Users\\Test\\Downloads\\javax.activation-1.2.0.jar");

Path tarProcessingJar =
    Path.of("C:\\Users\\Test\\archive-processor\\target\\archive-processor.jar");

Collection<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();
urls.add(jafJarPath.toUri().toURL());
urls.add(tarProcessingJar.toUri().toURL());

ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls.toArray(URL[]::new),
    ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader());
```

Now we can use it to load the class:

```
Class<? extends Runnable> archiveWriterClass =
    Class.forName("ArchiveWriter", true, loader).asSubclass(
        Runnable.class);

Runnable archiveWriter =
    archiveWriterClass.getConstructor(File.class).newInstance(archive);

archiveWriter.run();
```

If you need to pass more information and/or return information, you can use any interface other than Runnable.  You can even make up your own interface.  For example:

```
public interface Archiver {
    int createArchive(Path archive,
                      Path... sourceDirs)
    throws IOException;
}
```

And of course, ArchiveWriter can have any constructor(s) you wish, as long as you specify the constructor’s signature correctly when you call `getConstructor`.

Comment: ~List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();
 urls.add(activationJarURL);
 String[] systemClassPathEntries =for (String classpathEntry : systemClassPathEntries) { urls.add(Path.of(classpathEntry).toUri().toURL());
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls.toArray(URL[]::new),ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader());
Class<? extends Runnable> archiveWriterClass =
Class.forName("javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException", true, classLoader).asSubclass(Runnable.class); 
Runnable archiveWriter=archiveWriterClass.getConstructor(File.class).newInstance(archive);
archiveWriter.run();

Comment: i am getting error as 
 -----entered else---------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3924)
 at TestPackage.MimeException.main(MimeException.java:57). 
so the error is coming in the line
Class.forName("javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException", true, classLoader).asSubclass(Runnable.class);

Comment: Even tried with Class<? extends Runnable> archiveWriterClass =Class.forName("javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException.class", true,classLoader).asSubclass(Runnable.class);  but got the error  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException.class
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
at ""/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
at ""/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
at ""/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
at TestPackage.MimeException.main(MimeException.java:57)

Comment: Right, MimeTypeParseException does not implement Runnable, so of course it cannot be treated as a subclass of Runnable.  If you want to do Class.forName("javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException"), that’s fine, but don’t try to call asSubclass(Runnable.class) on that!

Comment: After adding all the changes you suggested still when it comes to the line TarArchive tar = new TarArchive(new FileOutputStream(archive)); it is giving same error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/MimeTypeParseException.

Comment: @user4888455 Updated and clarified logic.  Usually all classes in a single .jar or module are loaded with the same ClassLoader, so you will need to place the code that depends on Java Activation Framework in a separate .jar file.